# pass three dropdown selected values as a parameters via Ajax to controller

Tags: jquery

in jquery three dropdownlists values passing as  parameters via ajax  in button click event
but the value we store dropdownvalue cant we use out of the change function?

```
 $("#rooms").change(function () {
        var searchRooms = $("#rooms").val();       
 });
```

like this i need three varaibles(dropdownvalues) in button click event
i have three dropdownlists in view. i have selected one value from one dropdownlist using above code. now i need to select three values from three different dropdown lists.so if i use the above code to select one value from one dropdown then that value will be stored in searchRooms varaible.now i need to use(pass) the varaible to controller.if i close the change function i cant use the varaible value. am i correct? so i need to pass three dropdown list values to controller that to in button click event

> another issue,declaring as global variable.

```
  $(#"btn").click(function(){
    var searchRooms;
    var searchAdults;
    var searchChildren;
     $("#rooms").change(function () {
        searchRooms = $("#rooms").val();
    });

    $("#adults").change(function () {
        searchAdults = $("#adults").val();
    });

    $("#searchChildren").change(function () {
        searchChildren = $("#children").val();
    });

   $.ajax({
   i need pass the above three variable values to controller here
  });
  });
```

> in this after change function what will be the value of variable searchRooms?
>   in alert i am getting the value is undefined means,there is no value for searchRooms?
>   how can i pass that variable to controller?

Comment: Can you rephrase?  I'm having a hard time understanding what is currently being sent and what you want to send.  Some sample code wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: please take a few minutes to fully explain what it is you want...with html to support it. Question makes little sense even after it was updated

Comment: i have three dropdownlists in view. i have selected one value from one dropdownlist using above code. now i need to select three values from three different dropdown lists.so if i use the above code to select one value from one dropdown then that value will be stored in searchRooms varaible.now i need to use(pass) the varaible to controller.if i close the change function i cant use the varaible value. am i correct? so i need to pass three dropdown list values to controller

Comment: that to in button click event

Comment: post updates into question edit, not comments so the whole issue is in one place..and where's the html?

Answer (score 0):

You could define your variable `searchRooms` as a global (or some other suitable enclosing scope), outside of the scope of your `.change` function and it would be available when you do you AJAX call. Alternatively, you can just grab the values you need when you do your AJAX call exactly the same way you are doing it in your `.change` function.

In fact, as it stands right now, your `.change` function is doing nothing useful. You are grabbing the value from `#rooms` and putting it in a local variable that goes immediately out-of-scope. So it's not clear what you were trying to do there anyway.

So, you could do this:

```
var searchRooms;
$("#rooms").change(function () {
    searchRooms = $("#rooms").val();       
 });
```

Or, better, you could just do this:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
    var searchRooms = $("#rooms").val();
    var myotherdropdown = $("#otherdropdown").val();
    // now do your AJAX call, passing in your variables you grabbed above.
    $.ajax(//.....
});
```

*Update*: Something like this:

```
var searchRooms;
var searchAdults;
var searchChildren;

$("#rooms").change(function () {
    searchRooms = $("#rooms").val();
});

$("#adults").change(function () {
    searchAdults = $("#adults").val();
});

$("#searchChildren").change(function () {
    searchChildren = $("#children").val();
});

$(#"btn").click(function(){
   // How you pass the data here will depend on what you are calling and what format it's expecting. It *might* look something like this...
   $.ajax({
      data: { "searchRooms" : searchRooms, "searchAdults" : searchAdults, "searchChildren": searchChildren },
      // all your other settings for this ajax call...
   });
});
```

Comment: so how to define a searchRooms variable as global variable in jquery with in button click event

Comment: If a variable is defined outside of any function, it's global. So, as in the first example, `searchRooms` is defined outside of the `.change` function, so it is available to every function. A somewhat better way to do this however, is if all your function live inside your `$(function(){/*...*/})`, you can define your variable inside that function and the functions enclosed by it will be able to access those variables because of *closure*

Comment: ok thanx.the second way, won't work. because we cant get the value from dropdown simply using this line.var searchRooms = $("#rooms").val();. i didnt get the value actually. when i have used .change function i got the value into variable. so after three change functions,we can pass parameters via ajax call. anyway thanq :)

Comment: another issue,declaring as global variable.` $(#"btn").click(function(){ var searchRooms; var searchAdults; var searchChildren; $("#rooms").change(function (){searchRooms = $("#rooms").val(); });
    $("#adults").change(function () {  searchAdults = $("#adults").val();
    });
    $("#searchChildren").change(function () {
        searchChildren = $("#children").val();
    });
   $.ajax({
   i need pass the above three variable values to controller here
  });
  });`
in this after change function what will be the value of variable searchRooms?
in alert i am getting the value is undefined means